# Automatically run task that exports to excel and emails results through outlook

Tags: sql, automation, export, scheduled-tasks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Title explains it pretty much, but my goal is to run a query lets say once a week, this is occurring now through a TASK in snowflake.

I want to amend the TASK so the results are automatically exported to CSV and emailed, or simply just the results themselves emailed.

```
CREATE TASK IF NOT EXISTS LoadSuccessVsFail
    WAREHOUSE = ITSM_MWH
     SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 11 * * 3 Australia/Canberra' --thursdays at 11am
AS
    WITH    SUCCESSCTE AS (
SELECT  CLIENTNAME
,       COUNT(EVENTTYPE) AS SuccessLoad --count success load events for that game 
FROM    vw_fact_gameload60
WHERE   EVENTTYPE = 103 --success load events
    AND     USERTYPE = 1 --real users
    AND     APPID = 2 --titan games
    AND     FACTEVENTARRIVALDATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) --only looking at the last week  
GROUP BY CLIENTNAME
),

        FAILCTE AS ( --same as above but for failed loads
SELECT  CLIENTNAME
,       COUNT(EVENTTYPE) AS FailedLoads
FROM    vw_fact_gameload60
WHERE   EVENTTYPE = 106
    AND     USERTYPE = 1
    AND     APPID = 2
    AND     FACTEVENTARRIVALDATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY CLIENTNAME
)
SELECT  COALESCE(s.CLIENTNAME, f.CLIENTNAME) AS ClientName
,       ZEROIFNULL(s.SuccessLoad) + ZEROIFNULL(f.FailedLoads) AS TotalLoads --sum the success and failed loads found for 103, 106 events only, calculated in CTEs
,       ZEROIFNULL(s.SuccessLoad) AS Cnt_SuccessLoad --count from success cte
,       ZEROIFNULL(f.FailedLoads) AS Cnt_FailedLoads --count from fail cte
,       CONCAT(ZEROIFNULL(ROUND(s.SuccessLoad * 100.0 / TotalLoads,2)) , '%') As Pct_Success --percentage of SuccessLoads against total
,       CONCAT(ZEROIFNULL(ROUND(f.FailedLoads * 100.0 / TotalLoads,2)), '%') AS Pct_Fail---percentage of failedLoads against total
FROM    SUCCESSCTE s 
FULL OUTER JOIN FAILCTE f -- outer join in the fail CTE by game name, outer required because some titan games sucess or fail events are NULL  
            ON  s.CLIENTNAME = f.Clientname
ORDER BY CLIENTNAME ASC
```

Comment: What cloud are you using?

Comment: If you are on AWS, I'd consider looking into leveraging a Snowflake External Function to send the payload to a Lambda function that can convert the data to a Spreadsheet and then post that as a message to an SNS topic.  Then you can subscribe whatever emails that wish to receive the message.  Sounds like a lot of steps, but its easier than it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

there are many options depending upon what type of environment that you have, is it Cloud or on premise.

```
One way to go about is to do as follows.
1) Unload the data using Snowflake stage using the Copy command.
2) Down load the file into your server or local machine.
3) Write a script to email the files.
```

This link has more details
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-overview.html